# Complex numbers : find the value of  and 

Tags: complex-numbers

> The complex numbers $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are given by
>
> \begin{align}z_1&=-39+21i\\
> z_2&=-3+pi\\
> z_3&=q+3i\end{align}
>
> Given that $z_1=z_2z_3$, find the value of $p$ and $q$

**My Attempt**

\begin{align}-39+21i&=(-3+pi)(q+3i)\\
&=-3q-9i+qpi+3pi^2\end{align}

How do I proceed from here, can I move  things around the "="?

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by *Can I move things around the $=$*? Can you also tell us why you use an image to post instead of using Latex?

Comment: write $i^2$ as $-1$, group together the real and imaginary parts and compare the coefficients

Comment: I used an image to post because I don't know how to use mathjax so I just type in word in snip it

Comment: I have typed out your image in MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial so you can learn for next time

Comment: Thank you i will use mathjax next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$-39+21i=-3q-9i+qpi+3pi^2$$

We can rearrange the right hand side as follows, remembering that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ so $i^2=-1$:

\begin{align}-3q-9i+qpi+3pi^2&=-3q-9i+qpi+3p(-1)\\
&=-3q-9i+qpi-3p\\
&=(-3q-3p)+(-9+qp)i\end{align}

Now we can use the fact that two complex numbers are equal [if their real and imaginary parts are equal](https://www.theproblemsite.com/reference/mathematics/algebra/complex-numbers/equality), that is to say that \begin{align}-3q-3p&=-39\tag{real}\\
-9+qp&=21\tag{imaginary}\end{align}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Can u please proceed with the final answer? I can't seem to get it. Thanks

Comment: Have you studied simultaneous equations?

Comment: yes, i have but i don't remeber it well

Comment: Start by rearranging the first equation to have $p=\cdots$ and then put the value for $p$ into the second equation and solve for $q$

Comment: p=13-q
q=10 and 3.   is this correct?

Comment: That's correct, and now you can use those two values of $q$ back in the equation $p=13-q$ to find the corresponding values of $p$.

Comment: Thanks, my head almost exploded today its not easy for me

Comment: ok i got p=3 and 10, which value should i put into the question the next part is https://imgur.com/udEjsXM

Comment: You will have to do $p=3,q=10$ and then $p=10,q=3$ - both solutions are equally valid answers for the previous part of the question

Comment: Are you sure you have written down $z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$ correctly - the way your initial question was worded, it seems they are expecting only one value of $p$ and $q$

Comment: Yes, your right question only asked for one value for p and q. https://imgur.com/zJvFRDs i can use either (p=3,q=10) or (p=10,q=3) for the next part correct?

Comment: In that image, they have assumed that $i^2=1$ which is incorrect but may lead to a single value for $p,q$. Currently, the two options you have will give two different answers for the final part

Comment: Actually, reading again, they have specified that $p>q$ so you now only have one option